# Slack API - Pinning Messages

Tags: api, slack-api

I have been doing some work with the slack API recently, and it doesn't seem obvious how to pin a message using the Slack API, I see you can updated an existing message, so it doesn't seem like it is a limitation to get a hold of a message and do something with it.

Am I missing something obvious here or is there now API call to pin a message in a channel?

Comment: Craig, I can't delete my own answer because it's the Accepted one; But Erik has published a new answer because now it is possible. Please accept his answer instead, and I could delete mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `chat.update` nor `chat.postMessage` support pinning messages or adding new ones with pins.

In [two](https://api.slack.com/events/pin_added) [different](https://api.slack.com/events/message/pinned_item) pin-related APIs you can find the following note:

> The format of this message is still unstable and we expect to make changes to it in the future. *Until the pinning APIs are released* clients should ignore this event.

So unfortunately it looks like this can't be done currently, but a pinning API is in the works.

Answer (score 5):

It is now possible to pin messages using the Slack API. The Slack team has obviously added this functionality in the meantime.

You can now use: `pins.add` to pin a message or uploaded files to a channel

See [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/pins.add) for the documentation.